# Download a list of webpages in a file and rename them to avoid overwriting?

Tags: wget

```
$ wget -r -np  -nH --cut-dirs=2 -p -k "http://www.example.com/1" -O test.html
Cannot specify both -k and -O if multiple URLs are given, or in combination
with -p or -r. See the manual for details.

Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

I wonder how to solve the problem?

In my actual problem, I stored a list urls in a text file, such as

```
http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/2
http://www.example.com/3
```

I want to download each webpage with the necessary affiliated files to displace the webpage.

By default, each downloaded file is named `index.html`, so overwriting the previously downloaded webpage.
So I am trying to rename the downloaded files in numbers representing their downloading order:

```
i=0
for url in $(cat ../htmls); 
do  
wget -r -np  -nH --cut-dirs=1 -p -k "$url" -O $(printf %04d $i).html; 
i=$((i+1))
done
```

That is when the error at the beginning appears.

Comment: I removed the last line since it's a syntax error, so naturally fails, and is irrelevant to the rest of the question. You meant `i=$((i+1))`.

Answer (score 5):

You will need the `index.html` files since the various links in the webpages will rely on them. I would just save each webpage to its own directory:

```
while read url; do
    mkdir "$url";
    cd "$url"
    wget -r -np  -nH --cut-dirs=1 -p -k "$url"
    cd ../
done
```

As it turns out, `wget` already does this by default so use [Stephen's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210553/22222) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of `wget` with `-r` is to store downloaded files in directories matching the URL, so you could just let it do that:

```
wget -r -np -p -i myurls
```

(where `myurls` is your file containing the URLs to download).

The resulting mass of directories may not be most pleasing to you, but it will ensure you have everything you need to display the downloaded files, and that nothing gets overwritten...